# Email html detects if on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email

I have an ios app with a password reset feature. When a user hits password reset, I'm sending out a password reset email from my server and within the email is a link to a web page to reset the password.

This feels kind of clunky. I would like to know if it's possible have the email html detect if I am on an iphone and if so, have the link be a url scheme to open the app. then, from within the app, the user resets the pwd.

If anyone has any thoughts, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Universal Links

Use Universal Links. Apple delivered [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) to handle opening of the app when installed, and falling back to your chosen path mobile web, App Store.